# $H(\Omega)$ space of harmonic functions in $\Omega$. Show that $H(\Omega)$ is a closed subspace of $L^1(\Omega)$.

Tags: integration, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

> Let $\Omega$ be an open of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $H(\Omega)$ the space
>   constituted by the harmonic functions in $\Omega$ that belong to
>   $L^1(\Omega)$. Show that $H(\Omega)$ is a closed subspace of
>   $L^1(\Omega)$.

If $f\in H_1(\Omega)$ then $\int_{\Omega} |f|<\infty$ and also $\Delta f = 0$ in $\Omega$. For $g\in H_1(\Omega)$, we have

$f+g\in H_1(\Omega)$ because $\Delta(f+g) = \Delta f + \Delta g = 0$ and $\int_{\Omega} |f+g|\le \int_{\Omega} |f| +  \int_{\Omega}|g| < \infty$

$\lambda f\in H_1(\Omega)$ because $\Delta \lambda f = \lambda \Delta f = 0$ and $\int_{\Omega}\lambda f = \lambda  \int_{\Omega} f <\infty$

Is this it? I'm not so sure about the triangle inequality for integrals over regions like this. I know it works for integrals on one variable but why exactly can I use that? Why $\Omega$ must be open?

Comment: You've correctly shown that $H(\Omega)$ is a subspace (why are you skeptical about the triangle inequality? The proof is the same for integration over general sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for general measures), but that's the easy part. Showing that the $L^1$ limit of a sequence of harmonic functions is harmonic is the hard part.

Comment: @T.Bongers you're right, I totally forgot about showing it is closed

Comment: What if you take a $z_0$ is a disc in $\Omega$, and use the mean value property of harmonic functions, with the DCT to show the limit function is harmonic? Although I can't see right now how you get the necessary bound for the DCT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Omega$ must be open to define "harmonic". As Bongers said, you can do triangle inequality.

Suppose $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$, $f_n \in H(\Omega)$ for each $n$, and $f \in L^1(\Omega)$. By passing to a subsequence, we may assume $f_n \to f$ a.e.. Take $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$ such that $B_r(x) \subseteq \Omega$. Then $\int_{B_r(x)} f(y)dy = \lim_n \int_{B_r(x)} f_n(y)dy = \lim_n f_n(x) = f(x)$. Therefore $f$ is harmonic in $\Omega$, as desired.

There is a slight technicality with $f_n$ converging pointwise to $f$ almost everywhere, rather than everywhere. But I'll let you deal with this.

Comment: I'm reading it and will accept soon

Comment: why $ \lim_n \int_{B_r(x)} f_n(y)dy = \lim_n f_n(x) = f(x)$? I also would like to think on my own about the technicality you mentioned but I didn't noticed where the problem is

Comment: ok, I get it, you used the mean value property for harmonic functions. But for the pointwise convergence, I'm still thinking

Comment: why can we take the limit from inside the integral to outside?

Comment: I guess it's because $f_n$ is a bounded sequence that converges, then by the dominated convergence theorem it works. Am I right?

Comment: I still have no idea of the problem you talked about $f_n$ convergin pointwise

Comment: (1) I'm just using definition of $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$. (2) The issue I brought up is that when I say "$\lim_n f_n(x) = f(x)$", that is only true for a.e. $x$. The point is you have the mean value property almost everywhere. To get harmonicity, you need it everywhere. The issue is that $L^1$ functions are defined up to a measure 0 set of points. Of course, true harmonic functions are $C^\infty$, so there's no way an arbitrary representative of an $L^1$ function is harmonic. You need to redefine the function on that measure 0 set.